# What do/can/should you do if you daven Succos Hallel slower than the tzibur, and why?

Tags: halacha, tzibur-community, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hallel

If you daven Hallel on Succos slower than the shaliach tzibur, what do you do when everyone else gets to the parts that involve oral responses and/or shaking the lulav? Is it better to join in with that or finish Hallel in the order printed, shaking completely out of synch w the other daveners? Why? Is starting Hallel early a reasonable option?

Comment: Commonly the section that starts "Min Ha-Meitzar" and ends with "nagila v'nismecha bo" is recited very fast so the shaliach tzibbur finishes early. Yesterday he waited for everything to go quiet. This morning I was the shaliach tzibur and sang from "Od'cha" onwards albeit not as slow as on a festival day but allowed others to keep the pace, then  still ensured it was silent enough. I had a timetable in front of me and Hallel was intended to last 6 minutes.

Comment: As for your question, as you recited a B'racha over Hallel you almost certainly have to recite it all, even if you fall behind the tzibbur.

Comment: @CashCow  Is Hallel an all or none prayer and, in any case, can it be interrupted?  Is Hallel something that has to be said in order, or can I stop where I am and join with the others, and then go back and pick up where I left off?

Comment: @msh210 Why did you edit out my tag to tefilla? I am not complaining, I just want to know.

Comment: I thought 'hallel' was more precise and people would more likely be interested in the question if they're searching for 'hallel' questions than if they're searching more generally for 'tefilla' questions. (We could leave both tags in, but I think the five tags now on the question pretty much don't overlap ('sukkot' and 'esrog' are kind-of an exception) so are better than including 'tefilla'.) If you disagree, by all means re-edit!

Comment: My guess is that you do need to say all the tehillim. If you reach Hodu when the minyan has passed it (or if you are davening alone) you shake on the first 2 verses like the shaliach tzibur (as of course you will be saying all 4 and not responding). If you know you will end up behind if you start the same time as the rest you probably can grab your arba minim the moment the shaliach tzibur ends chazarat hashatz, say the bracha over it and shake it then start hallel. (If the shaliach tzibur is removing tefillin too you have even more time).